# How to speed up bvh creation (with hair particles)

Tags: rendering, particles, hair, bvh

I am trying to render a hair animation with 10k particles and interpolated children with hair dynamics, which results in more time spent creating the bvh for each frame than actually rendering it in cycles.

If anyone knows how to improve the bvh creation times that would be great.